# Dancer plugin loading a template

Tags: perl, plugins, dancer

How can I load a template from a Dancer::Plugin which is not in 'app/views' directory without changing views default directory?

This isn't working /it adds the default views path to the file path/:

```
package Dancer::Plugin::MyPlugin;
use Dancer ':syntax';
use Dancer::Plugin;

any '/test' => sub {
    template '/path_to_template/test.tt' => {
    };
};

register_plugin;

1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could call `engine` to get the `Dancer::Template` object and call its `render` method, e.g.:

```
my $template_engine = engine 'template';
my $content = $template_engine->render('/path/to/template.tt', { 'name' => 'value' });
```

Then, to return the rendered content in the default layout, call `apply_layout`:

```
return $template_engine->apply_layout($content);
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently, I think you'd need to set the `views` setting before the template call, then change it back afterwards, for instance:

```
my $views_dir = setting('views');       # remember current setting
setting 'views' => '/some/other/path';  # temporarily use our desired path
my $content = template 'test', $params; # render the view
setting 'views' => $views_dir;          # restore previous setting
return $content;
```

That, however, is ugly.

I think it would make sense for the `template` keyword to accept a `system_path` option, much like `send_file` does, so you could say, e.g.:

```
template '/path/to/view.tt', $params, { system_path => 1 };
```

I've raised an issue for this, and will look in to getting it implemented for the next release: https://github.com/sukria/Dancer/issues/645

(Disclosure: I'm part of the Dancer dev team)

Comment: 10q for the effort! ^^ I think that I have a better idea: each plugin could have it's own 'views' dir and 'public' dir like an actual app, don't you think?